# SQL Server 2014 not accessible from network

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have setup a SQL Server 2014 instance on my local drive/computer and everything is working fine. I can login and access the data inside. I have the role admin on both the SQL server and my local computer. The computer is in an AD of a network. However, if I go to a different computer in the network, (I can ping to and from machine in the network no problem) and attempt to login my SQL server 2014 under the same credentials using Windows Authentication, I got the error below:

[image]

I have checked the configuration on my local machine where the SQL server 2014 resides and have all protocol enabled.
[image]

I also have SQL Server service set to automatic:

[image]

What else do I need to look into to make sure my SQL Server can be accessible from the network? My local computer OS is Windows 8.1.
Please help as the SQL Server is pretty useless if only my local machine can access the data in the SQL Server.

Comment: You'll want to make sure any intervening firewalls have the necessary ports open (e.g. TCP 1433 is the default instance port). (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)

Comment: @Jacob: Thank you for the fast response. I do not see TCP 1433 being blocked in my Windows Firewall. Do I need to explicitly allow it? If not what other ports may be relevant? I do not want to open irrelevant ports as it could create security risk. Thanks again!

Comment: You might have to add an explicit rule to allow it. Maybe try turning the firewall off briefly to try to isolate the issue. Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795863/cant-connect-to-sql-2012-remotely-by-ip-and-named-instance

Comment: Server name resolution might be the problem, try adding the IP of your SQL Server to your local hosts file to confirm.

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks again. I have added inbound rule for port TCP/UDP 1434 and ports TCP 443, 1433, my outbound rules are open to all ports. Allowed remote access (it was default also) but still no progress.

Comment: @MWillemse: My system is Windows 8.1 not a windows server. Does it have a local hosts file. If it does, how do I locate it?

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc (you could probably confirm also by using the ip of the server instead of the domain name)

Did you change the firewall on both server and client? Are there any other firewalls in your network?

Comment: @Jacob: Thanks! My "server" is actually a Windows 8.1. I can see the host file. But problem is my system seems to use ipV6 instead of the traditional xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. I am programmer and have limited knowledge about the admin stuff. How do I record the ip address? put down xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx as is? And yes there are other rules in the network but since I am not network admin, I do not know its policy. I can ask the system admin to open ports if I am specific enough. I believe my other 'client' ports are open because I can ssis from it to other sql servers, just not this one

Comment: Same here, I'm more of a programmer and you may need help from whomever owns your network. I wonder if you might get better help from a different site such as: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server